# Proof question about continuous function achieving its supremum on a compact set

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

**Definition:** A set is *compact* if for any sequence in $A$, there exists a subsequence converging to a point in A.

**Theorem:** Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be a compact set and $f : A \to \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function. Then there exists an $x_1 \in A$ such that $f(x_1)=M= \sup\{f(x): x \in A\}.$

In the book, the proof goes as follows: Suppose that for all $x \in A$ we have $f(x) < M $. Therefore, there exists an $n$ such that $M - \frac{1}{n} > f(x)$. Then  since $x_n \in A$ and $x_{n_{k}} \to x$, it follow that $x\in A$ (by compactness of $A$). It follows that $$M - \frac{1}{n_k} < f(x_{n_{k}}) \leq M.$$

Last inequality is not clear to me. How has it come?

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Comment: MathJax works in the title section, too, don't you know?

Comment: I think you've got a few typos in your proof : assuming $M$ is the supremum of $f$ over $A$, you have that $\forall n\ge 1, \exists x_n\in A :  f(x_n) \ge M - \frac{1}{n}$. The last inequality is the same with $n\equiv n_k$

Comment: @Shaun its from youtube video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9mw2-y-ybIo&list=PLDzvuf9Uf4FN7dUzrIyQ8Z6vyqo8UV_R4&index=2&t=950s&ab_channel=SKumaresan

Comment: Please [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: @StratosFair how have you written inequality ?

Comment: this is from the definition of supremum : it's the smallest number $M$ such that $f(x)\le M\forall x$. In particular, for any number $M' < M$, there exists some $x^*$ such that $f(x^*) > M'$. I applied that to $M' := M- 1/n$

Comment: @StratosFairyes that would be an element of A but how come proof writes sequence inA , instead of element

Comment: @StratosFair or are they talking about constant sequence of some element in A ?

Comment: For each $n\ge 1$ define $M'(n) := M - 1/n$. If you followed what I write above, then you get that for each $M'(n)$ there exists $x(n)\equiv x_n \in A$ such that $f(x_n) > M'(n)$. This does define a sequence $(x_n)$ of elements of $A$.

Comment: @MathFail edited. M is supremum of range of f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof from your book means the following:

Since $M$ is the supremum of $f$ on $A$,

For $\epsilon=1, \exists x_1\in A$, s.t $M-1<f(x_1)\le M$,

For $\epsilon=\frac{1}2, \exists x_2\in A$, s.t $M-\frac{1}2<f(x_2)\le M$,

...

For $\epsilon=\frac{1}n, \exists x_n\in A$, s.t $M-\frac{1}n<f(x_n)\le M$,

Since $A$ is compact, we can find a subsequence $x_{n_k}$ of $\{x_n\}$, s. t $x_{n_k}\rightarrow c\in A$, so we have

$$M-\frac{1}{n_k}<f(x_{n_k})\le M$$

$$\lim \left(M-\frac{1}{n_k}\right)\le\lim  f(x_{n_k})\le \lim M$$

Since $f$ is continuous, $\lim  f(x_{n_k})=f(\lim x_{n_k})=f(c)$, we get:

$$M\le  f(c)\le M$$

Therefore, $f$ attains its supremum $M$ at $x=c\in A$, which is the maximum.

Comment: Thanks a lot...

Comment: you are welcome